# What if branch A is removed after merge into branch B?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

To be straight forward...

> 1. I have branch A and two other branches B and C which were created based on branch A.
> 2. I generally do changes on branch A and then manually merge changes on B and C if required.
> 3. But what would happen if I do SVN Merge (A -> B) for few revisions and then branch A get deleted (may be a case A is no longer
>      required after some time)?

Any help would be heartily appreciated.

Comment: If you are working with multiple repositories wouldn't it make more sense to use a VCS that supports that (e.g. GIT or Mercurial)?

Comment: @Robert, actually I am using multiple repositories because it requires to only merge specific functionality and not all. Previously it happened that one of main branch was removed after making new branch as main branch. So I am curious for above question.

Comment: Are you using multiple repositories, or is this a single repository with multiple projects in it? When you say Repository A gets deleted, are you talking about taking that repository down, or are you talking about deleting a project?

Comment: @DavidW., It's a branch. I corrected my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you delete a branch after a merge? Nothing. The merge already took place, so the merged history is still there. The `svn:mergeinfo` property even lists the branch that was deleted.

What happens if you try to merge a deleted branch? Nothing. You can't. Subversion will tell you that branch no longer exists.

However, nothing in Subversion is ever deleted. You can always undo an action -- even a deletion of a branch. Let's say you deleted your `foo` branch in revision 1001, you could revive it with this:

```
$ svn cp -r1000 $REPO/branches/foo@1000 $REPO/branches
```

The `-r1000` says that you're interested in revision 1000 of your repository. Since you deleted the revision in revision 1001, you are talking about the revision *before* the deletion.

The `@1000` on the end of the URL is called *pinning*. It's saying you're looking at the *structure* of the repository at revision 1000 when that branch was still around.

Or, you could undo a merge of revision 1001 when the branch was deleted:

```
$ svn co --depth=immediates $RSVP/branches
```

The `immediates` will get you the branch names, but not their content.

```
$ cd branches
$ svn merge -c -1001
```

This will remove the changes in revision 1001 which is the revision when the branch was deleted. Note that the `svn cp` used the revision *before* the deletion and this uses the revision when the deletion occurred.

Once the branch has been *recreated*, you can go forward with merging as if nothing happened.

One thing you cannot do `svn add` to add the branch back in:

```
$ svn co --depth=immediates $RSVP/branches
$ cd branches
$ svn mkdir foo
$ ...   # Copying the files back in
$ svn add -R .
```

This will create a *new* branch called `foo` with no shared history between your trunk or the branch. The files will have the same names, but Subversion will look at them as completely different files. Attempts at merging will only lead to heartaches and emotional distress.